# "Меня это улыбнуло"

Tags: лексика

Сейчас частенько можно встретить в интернете и услышать от других слово "улыбнуло". То есть не насмешило, не развеселило, а именно заставило улыбнуться. Понятно, что в словарях русского языка этого слова нет, но, как вы думаете, есть ли у него шансы туда попасть? По-моему, слово емкое, сродни тем, которые приводит К.И. Чуковский в книге "От двух до пяти": *"что это за перелай такой?"* и т.д.?

Answer (score 1):

> Понятно, что в словарях русского языка этого слова нет, но, как вы думаете, есть ли у него шансы туда попасть?

В нормативные - нет. В ближайшее время. Для этого сначала глагол "улыбаться" должен избавиться от возвратного суффикса - и стать переходным. А это, даже только вторая стадия, - очень долгий процесс. А что касается ненормативного употребления, то такие глаголы - сплошь и рядом. "Его ушли", "меня заснули" и прочее. В какие-то словари, естественно, попадают.

И главное, есть нормативные синонимы... Это тоже не способствует.

Answer (score 0):

Слово, действительно, очень милое. Может, и приживется.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую это слово в шутливом оазговоре, но в словари может попасть только как явный окказионализм. У него очень узкая сфера употребления.

Answer (score 0):

Слову "улыбнуло" уже более 200 лет.

Обратимся к толковому словарю Владимира Ивановича Даля:

> Улыбнуть кого, калужск. твер. обмануть, надуть, не дать посуленого.
>   Видно тебя улыбнули, только посулили, а не дадут. Вероятно это вышло
>   от шуточного выраженья: вещь улыбнулась, пропала, нет ее.

Источник: http://russkiiyazyk.ru/interesno/ulyibnulo.html

Comment: У Fuchoin Kazuki.«Меня это  у л ы б н у л о», а не «улыбнулось». Есть примеры с   у л ы б н у л о?

Answer (score -1):

Оно есть в словарях. В частности в словаре синонимов Тришина.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/385842/%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE

Comment: Это не нормативный словарь. С точки зрения орфоэпии - на уровне какого-нибудь словаря воровского жаргона.

Comment: Вы явно не общались с недавно откинувшимися (вот это из жаргона, да) ворами. Они так не говорят, уверяю.. :)

Comment: В то время, как я даю линки людям на полезную информацию, вы очень забавно пытаетесь корчить из себя ментора. Не забудьте подтереть за собой комменты, кстати после беседы... :)